# Angular http post adds multiple empty objects after adding user data to json

Tags: angular, http-post, httpclient

[image].ts:

```
addProduct(productForm:NgForm){


  this.productService.addProduct(productForm.value).subscribe((res:any)=>
    res= this.addProduct(res)

  );

 }
```

.service:

```
addProduct(productForm:NgForm) {

        return this.httpObj.post<products>(`${this.uri}/products`,productForm,{
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
    });
```

when I enter the form data and submit, last entered data gets overwritten  and new data is entered.After new data, multiple empty rows are inserted.What could be the issue?

Comment: hmm, could be a back end issue? go into the network tab, and take a screenshot of the payload you are sending to the server. lets have a look at it

Comment: I have added pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addProduct(productForm:NgForm){
    this.productService.addProduct(productForm.value).subscribe((res:any)=>
        res= **this.addProduct(res)**
    );  
}
```

You have an unwanted recursion going on.

Comment: Thank u..found that helpful